# Is the in-app billing subscription EXPIRED order id supposed to be the same as the PURCHASED order id?

Tags: android

I finally had a monthly subscription expire, but in 2 of 3 cases with multiple devices the order id was different.  The PURCHASED order id was "123.abc" and the EXPIRED order id was only "abc".  On one of the devices the order ids were the same.  I'm not sure which device was the original purchase device since it was a month ago.  I just made a new monthly subscription purchase and it's order id is "456.def".

There doesn't appear to be a reasonable way to test in-app subscription expiration full circle.

Answer (score 0):

The answer appears to be YES.

In my case, I cleared my app data which forced a restore of transactions.  This only included the EXPIRED order id.  Additionally, a new subscription purchase included 2 orders with a "456.def" and "def" order ids.  I guess this is some sort of fix on the Google Play end.